# variables in script with setup enabled isn't accessible in Vue template

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

This is not vue related but Vue-cli I believe. The `greet` binding won't appear in the DOM.

```bash
<script setup>
 const greet = "hello world";
 console.log(greet);
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">The greet is not working {{ greet }}</div>
</template>
```

It throws an error in the console

```bash
[Vue warn]: Property "greet" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <App>
```

Here is the working code, it is a simple template from codesanbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-villani-0qk4zz?file=/src/App.vue:0-156

Comment: Vue CLI isn't directly responsible for this. Other Vue packages do. You may notice there's `[@vue/compiler-sfc] <script setup> is still an experimental proposal` message. Means that the package is too old and causes incorrect behaviour.

Comment: @EstusFlask so you mean I should completely disease from using the template I'm using presently?
It's the official one on the codesanbox. that aside, any idea how I could resolve it?

Comment: I mean that you can at least try to update deps from package.json. That it's official means that it's not properly maintained, you can open an issue if there's an open bugtracker for the site

Comment: According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73650573/vue3-codesandbox-unexpected-token-using-script-setup), it seems the `<script setup>` may have compatibility issues with codesandbox.

Comment: @ggorlen you are right. I discovered it wasn't compatible with codesanbox. Codesanbox already resolved it with a bite template. I guess vue-cli wouldn't work altogether and vite should be preferred over vue-cli

Comment: I meant a vite* in every place you see bite. It's an autocorrect typo.